# How can I customize an html menu in Wordpress using wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: wordpress

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="top"><a href="index.php" class="top_link"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="top"><a href="index.php" class="top_link"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
  <li class="top"><a href="index.php" class="top_link"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
  <li class="top"><a href="index.php" class="top_link"><span>Registration</span></a></li>
  <li class="top"><a href="index.php" class="top_link"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Help! I am new to Wordpress.

Comment: You can discard the <span> it has no function, all styles can be applied to the <a>

Comment: You can start with explaining how you want to customize it. There are a few different options depending on the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use get_pages() then do whatever I like with the layout in the foreach loop.

[get_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)